# batch bitstransfer url with white spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file. I use it to download installers (vlc.exe, VC++ 2008 redistributable package vcredist_x86.exe, etc) from web. Recently I downloaded VC++ 2008 redistributable package and it worked fine with this syntax:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer '%URL%' '%downloadPath%'
```

I set the VC++ 2008 download link in URL and C:\Temp in downloadPath.

I have heard on other forums about using wget and curl but I would still like to use Start-BitsTransfer.

**Now the problem is** when I tried to download WAMP (from WAMP website which redirects to sourceforge.net website) using this same syntax I get the error

> ERROR CODE:    0x80190194 - HTTP status 404: The requested URL does not exist

After much  poking at the URL I saw that the WAMP download url has `/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/` (I guess for single white space). So when the Start-BitsTransfer executes this, I am guessing it some how messes up the url (I am not sure how).

Can someone tell me with example code how to download WAMP using this syntax
`Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer '%URL%' '%downloadPath%'`?

Or can someone tell me with example code how to download WAMP using PowerShell?

Comment: Uhm, what exactly are you doing there? That looks like a weird mix of PowerShell and batch syntax, which ... doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Try escaping each `%` inside the url by doubling it.

Comment: Hey wOxxOm, your suggestion of doubling the % inside the url has worked!. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Joey, I am trying to run a batch file which has this powershell command to download WAMP from its webstie. If you goto the WAMP website and click on download it will redirect you to sourceforge.net and the download will begin in a few seconds.While waiting here, If I click on direct link there (if I have something like IDM, FDM or something, I can have a look at the actual download url). This particular url has /WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/ within it which was causing the problem. I was using this url in my Start-BitsTransfer command. Anyways, thank you for replying back and helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` are used to expand variables in batch file language, so you have to escape each `%` inside the url by doubling it:

```
/WampServer%%202/Wampserver%%202.5/
```